# Add static columns to pivot table from related tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a couple of related tables in Excel: Projects, and Purchases. Projects has the following columns:

Project Name, Initial Budget

Purchases has the following columns:

Project, Item, Cost

I've created a relationship using Project Name as the Primary key, and Project as foreign key. Purchases is many-to-one relationship with Projects.

I am looking to create a Pivot Table to show total cost for each project, but also want to show the Initial Budget as extra static column, just shown as-is without any calculations. My Pivot Table should have the following columns:

Project, Sum of Cost, Initial Budget

I want the cost summed, but want to show the Initial Budget next to each project, so I can compare if I am over budget or not. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Each project has only one budget, this means that if you have the budget in the same table as the Purchases table, then you could use the budget and summarise it as either one of: minimum, maximum or average, all of the three operations should give you the same results because one project has only one budget. To add the budget, you can then use a simple `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,0)
```

I'll use maximum in this example:

[image]

Of course, you can rename the header name to something like 'Budget' (not 'Initial Budget' however because Excel will complain the name already exists).

---

You could also put the budget in the Rows section, but you will have to do a little more to make it a little more to make it similar to the above. You will have to change the report layout to 'Tabular' and turn off subtotals (in which case you won't have to rename the heading):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Power Query to get the result, follow these steps:

1. add 2 tables to Power Query editor as queries, merge queries and expanded it:
   [image]
2. Unpivot Columns Cost- Pivot Columns Attribute and Cost directly- select Value and Sum
   [image]
3. Close and load